# javascript - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript

Just one of those times when I just can't see the problem.  It appears to be the opening brace at the end of the if statement.

```
  $('#title_number').change(function () {
    if ($('#title_number').val() == 73) or ($('#title_number').val() == 74) {
    $('#ProfessorDiv').show();
    }
  });
```

Comment: There is no `or` keyword in JavaScript, and the *entire* expression used by the `if` must be in `()`.

Comment: Jiminey Christmas!  How many time have I coded an or statement. embarassing.

Answer (score 4):

Your `if` statement is malformed (parenthesis grouped `or`, not the entire expression):

```
if ($('#title_number').val() == 73 || $('#title_number').val() == 74) {
  $('#ProfessorDiv').show();
}
```

Also there is no such [logical operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) as `or`. You meant `||`.